# Clarifications needed in the definition in making a module into an algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I found the following definition for how to make a module over a ring into an algebra:

> Let $R$ be a commutative unitary ring.  By an $R-$algebra we shall mean an $R-$module $A$ together with an internal law of composition $A\times A\mapsto A$, described by $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ and called $\textit{multiplication,}$ which is distributive over addition and such that 
> $(\forall\lambda\in R)(\forall x,y\in A) $ $\lambda(xy)=(\lambda x)y=x(\lambda y)$

The author then further states:

> "By imposing conditions on the multiplication in the above definition we obtain various types of algebra.  For example, if the multiplication is associative then $A$ is called an $\textit{associative algebra}$ (note that in this case $A$ isa ring under its internal laws of addition and multiplication); if the multiplication is commutative then $A$ is called a $\textit{commutative algebra};$ if there is a multiplicative identity element in $A$ then $A$ is said to be $\textit{unitary}.$  A unitary associative algebra in which every non-zero element has an inverse is called a $\textit{division algebra}.$"

I have a few questions about the common definition of an algebra use in the context of modules.
(1) when a module say $M$ defined over a ring $R$, the module $M$ is called a vector space over the ring $R$ even though $R$ might not be a field?
(2) The definition of an algebra for a module makes the ring $R$ acting on $M$ a bilinear map?
(3) when speaking of a module $M$ being either an associative or a commutative or a unital algebra and needing to satisfied: $(\forall\lambda\in R)(\forall x,y\in A) $ $\lambda(xy)=(\lambda x)y=x(\lambda y)$, does it mean for associativity:

$\forall\lambda\in R$ and $\forall x, y, z \in M$ $\lambda x(yz)=\lambda (xy)z$
 or does it mean 
 $\forall\lambda\in R$ and $\forall x, y \in M$ $\lambda (xy)=(\lambda x)y$

For being commutative, which one of the following does it mean:

$\forall\lambda\in R$ and $\forall x, y \in M$ $\lambda (xy)=\lambda (yx)$
 or does it mean 
 $\forall\lambda\in R$ and $\forall x\in M$ $\lambda x=x\lambda$

Lastly the module $M$ being an unital $R-$algebra, since $M$ is already an additive abelian group, does both $M$ and $R$ has to have its own identity elements (multiplicative for $M$ or additive or multiplicative for $R$) or is it only that one of $M$ or $R$ needs to have both an additive and a multiplicative identity. 
  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when a module say $M$ defined over a ring $R$, the module $M$ is called a vector space over the ring $R$ even though $R$ might not be a field?

No, $M$ would only be an $R$-vector space if $R$ is a field. That said, it's definitely possible for someone to accidentally refer to a module as a vector space. Many results about vector spaces generalise to modules - for example, a linear map $R^n \to R^n$ is invertible if and only if the determinant of the relevant matrix is a unit.

Many applications of algebras are when the ring is a field. For example, the Stone-Weierstrass theorem deals with $\mathbb{R}$-algebras (which are, of course, vector spaces).

> The definition of an algebra for a module makes the ring $R$ acting on $M$ a bilinear map?

In fact, we only need $M$ to be a module for the multiplication function $(r \in R, m \in M) \mapsto r \cdot m$ to be bilinear. This is one of the axioms of a module. So an algebra structure on $M$ is not relevant here.

Associativity here means that $\forall a, b, c \in M (a(bc) = (ab)c)$. Your first statement $\forall \lambda \in R \forall x, y, z \in M (\lambda (x(yz)) = \lambda ((xy) z)$ is equivalent to this claim (in particular, in the case where $\lambda = 1$). Your second statement $\forall \lambda \in R \forall x, y \in M (\lambda (xy) = (\lambda x) y)$ is part of the definition of an algebra.

For being commutative, what is meant is that $\forall a, b \in M (ab = ba)$. Your first statement $\forall \lambda \in R (\forall x, y \in M (\lambda (xy) = \lambda (yx))$, is equivalent to commutativity. Your second statement, $\forall \lambda \in R \forall x \in M (\lambda x = x \lambda)$ doesn't make any sense, since $x \lambda$ does not make any sense.

Being unitary simply means there is some $e \in M$ such that $\forall x \in M (x = ex = xe)$. Note that a unit, if it exists, is unique, since if we had units $e_1$ and $e_2$ then $e_1 = e_1 e_2 = e_2$. Generally, we would only require the algebra to be unitary if $R$ is also unitary.

If $R$ is a (not necessarily commutative) unital ring, then we can describe an associative unital $R$-algebra as some (not necessarily commutative) unital ring $M$ together with a ring homomorphism $i : R \to M$. It's easy to show that every unital associative $R$-algebra $M$ is a ring with the ring homomorphism map $i(x) = x \cdot 1$ (where $1$ is the unit in $M$); conversely, the other direction gives us an $R$-algebra from a ring $M$ together with $i : R \to M$ through the module structure $(r, m) \mapsto i(r) \cdot m$. Of course, the requirement that $M$ moreover be a commutative algebra is easily expressed as requiring $M$ as a ring to be commutative.

Comment: classic examples for a non associative algebra would be the lie algebra as a module and a classic example for a non commutative algebra would be matrix rings as non commutative ring in the sense of multiplication is non commutative.   The reason I have two statements for unital, associative and commutative is because, I am not sure if the operations refers to elements in the abelian group $M$ or the ring $R$ acting on it or is it applying to cases of both at the same time because as vector spaces, there is the notion of compatibility of scalar, vector addition and multiplications.

Comment: are my examples correct matching for what the typical non commutative or non associative algebras?

Comment: @SethMai Yes, those are the canonical examples of non-commutative and non-associative algebras.

Comment: I checked over my post one last time, I think for (1) I meant to ask, to make a module into an algebra, the module does not necessarily need to be over a ring which is considered as a field.  Meaning, I can have a $M$ module over a general ring to be considered as an algebra?  In some text, I don't see the requirement that it has to be defined over a field.  I am not if the omission is meant to imply that it is defined over a field or not necessarily so.  As for commutativity, I ask if it meant that $\lambda x)=x\lambda)$, I ask about that because if commutativity...

Comment: ...if commutativity means commutative with w.r.t multiplication of a vector with a scalar or is it only commutative multiplication with respect to vectors.

Comment: Yes, you can have an algebra over a ring which is not a field. There is no constraint that $R$ be a field. For example, if $R$ is commutative and unital, then $R[X]$ is the free associative commutative unital $R$-algebra on 1 element. For commutativity, it doesn't make sense to ask whether multiplication between a scalar and a vector is commutative. If $\lambda$ is a scalar and $x$ a vector, then the expression $x \lambda$ is meaningless.